# Como criar tupla com chave recebendo valor?

Tags: python, django, tupla, django-queryset

Gostaria de criar um método que retorna os parametros do FILTER da ORM do Django. Vou ter que usar esses filtros em diversos momentos, gostaria de criar esse método genérico. Segue o exemplo:

```
def home(selected_page=None):
    _config = Config.objects.filter()
    _config = _config.filter(filter_config_by_page(selected_page))
    return _config

def filter_config_by_page(selected_page):
    final_tuple = ()
    if selected_page == "work":
        final_tuple = (works__user__isnull = False,)
    elif selected_page == "not-work":
        final_tuple = (works__user__isnull = True,)
    elif selected_page == "solved":
        final_tuple = (status = 2,)
    elif selected_page == "not-solved":
        final_tuple = (status = 3,)
    return final_tuple
```

**Erro**

```
File "/myapp/configuerson/controller/configs.py", line 101
    final_tuple = (works__user__isnull = False,)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Acredito, segundo o erro que apareceu, que não posso atribuir valor a tuplas que estou criando dessa forma. Teria alguma forma de fazer o `filter_config_by_page` funcionar seguindo essa lógica que descrevi?

Comment: Agora que vi que você quer criar um filtro pro Django, vou dar uma lida na documentação e, se conseguir entender como funciona, eu posto algo aqui.

Comment: Sim, um método apenas para construir o filtro do Django. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de retornar uma tupla, você pode retornar um dicionário com os parâmetros que quer utilizar no filtro. Daí basta expandir o dicionário usando `**`:

```
def home(selected_page=None):
    _config = Config.objects.filter()
    kwargs = filter_config_by_page(selected_page)
    _config = _config.filter(**kwargs)
    return _config

def filter_config_by_page(selected_page):
    final_tuple = {}
    if selected_page == "work":
        final_tuple = {"works__user__isnull": False}
    elif selected_page == "not-work":
        final_tuple = {"works__user__isnull": True}
    elif selected_page == "solved":
        final_tuple = {"status": 2}
    elif selected_page == "not-solved":
        final_tuple = {"status": 3}
    return final_tuple
```